# Modify 'Soft Limit' of 'Max processes'

Tags: linux, process, proc, ulimit

I tried `ulimit -u 2000` and `ulimit -Su 2000` to modify the '*Max processes*', and started up my program, but failed. I found file '/proc/pid/limit' is still:

```
Max processes             1024                 2000                 processes
```

How could I change the soft limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does `ulimit -a` show?

You're likely at the global max limit or are encountering a permissions issue. I tried your experiment and it worked just fine for me.

#### Example

The output of a `/proc/pid/limits` looks like the following:

```
$ cat /proc/22666/limits | grep processes
Max processes             1024                 62265                processes 

$ ulimit -a | grep processes
max user processes              (-u) 1024
```

Setting the soft limit to 2000:

```
$ ulimit -Su 2000

$ ulimit -a | grep processes
max user processes              (-u) 2000

$ cat /proc/22666/limits | grep processes
Max processes             2000                 62265                processes
```

#### What else?

I'd take a look at your `/etc/security/limits.conf` file and see if there is a limit coming from that file that's keeping regular users from changing this limit

I'd also look in the directory, `/etc/security/limit.d/`. There are additional files often times there which include more limits. For example on my Fedora system I have this file:

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf 
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     1024
```

#### References

- [How do I increase the open files limit for a non-root user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user)

Comment: Actually the `/proc/pid/limit` output he shows indicates the hard limit is at 2000 and the soft limit still at 1024.